# VS 2017 Test Explorer not showing Tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have a Unit Test Project (targeting .net 4.5.2) that has 100s of tests in it.  It was working fine in test explorer and running properly for a few weeks.  A few days ago, VS 2017 crashed on me and when I reloaded it Test Explorer no longer showed any tests.  I've done a variety of steps (like deleting %TEMP%\VisualStudioExtensions) that were mentioned in other related questions but nothing has seemed to work.

What's worse is that I've tried adding a new Unit Test project and, with the default test, just threw an assert fail and even that test isn't showing up in test explorer.

After messing with this for a few days, I'm starting to get worried that I will need to do something bananas like uninstall/reinstall VS 2017 to get these back (although I have no real faith that that will work).

My questions are:

1) Any ideas on what I can do to bring these test back or maybe fully reset test explorer so that it somehow forces those tests to be recognized?

2) Does anybody have any recommendations for alternative test runners outside of VS 2017.  I'd hate to use another tool to run my tests, but at this point, I'm scared that this will happen at a critical time and I just won't have time to fiddle around with things again.

**UPDATE**
I had dependencies on XUnit and FluentAssertions.  When I remove the XUnit dependency, it seems to be recognizing tests again.  There were no errors thrown or being logged by VS during build so I'm not sure what was going wrong.  If anybody has any ideas, I'd love to hear it.  I'd also still like to have some backup option for running my tests because we use XUnit extensively so re-writing these tests will be a pain and I would prefer not doing this again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, XUnit was the issue.  I'm guessing that there's some conflict between it and VS 2017 (I never had this issue in VS2015).  Once I removed the reliance on XUnit, the tests started showing up again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the case here, but try checking the platform target in your test project properties. (Right click on a project > Build) Make sure it's Any CPU, or the same as in your project.

As for other tools, ReSharper works pretty well. Together with DotCover you can also see code coverage line by line.

Comment: I tried the processor targeting that you mentioned but still no luck.  It does seem that the issue was with Test Explorer and XUnit.  I removed the dependency on XUnit for a group of tests and Test Explorer started showing the tests again.  Very weird.  

DotCover may be the replacement I am looking for though.  I really like that it integrates in VS.